# Invalid QgsRasterLayer when attempting to load a Google Static Maps API image into QGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis

In the QGIS Python console, this block of code returned a valid object in QGIS 2.16.3 and I think 2.18.6. I could view the static image in QGIS.

```
>>> reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
>>> raster = QgsRasterLayer('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51,0&zoom=10&size=2550x3300', 'test')
>>> raster.isValid()
>>> reg.addMapLayer(raster)
```

At least since 2.18.9 (tested 2.18.15 as well), `raster.isValid()` returns False.

This is not specific to the Google Static Maps API. The code block also used to work if loading other PNG/JPG images.

Am I missing a required component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `http` instead of `https`:

```
reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
raster = QgsRasterLayer('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51,0&zoom=10&size=2550x3300', 'test')
raster.isValid()
reg.addMapLayer(raster)
```

[image: Result]

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.18.14.*

Comment: Does this mean SSL requests in qgis are broken? What if we need to send the request over ssl for compliance reasons?

Comment: @AlexanderN. - Check this post to see how to authenticate such requests: [QGIS Handling of HTTPS URL Strings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229446/qgis-handling-of-https-url-strings). It's not something I have used regularly :)

Comment: @Joseph thanks! Using HTTP works on Windows but seems to fail on Mac/Linux. I've posted a new question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266485/invalid-qgsrasterlayer-when-attempting-to-load-an-image-into-qgis-mac-but-not

Comment: @ash - Most welcome, glad it works for Windows. Unfortunately, I don't have a Linux machine to test it on but hopefully others can provide a solution :)